# How to fix Click event while using several Labels in a form for display from Listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am making a program that will display a listbox and select from among the list items when i right_clicked a label using the _Mouseclicked event and also show a colorDialog when i right_clicked the label to change the background color. However, the problem is that, i have several labels on the form to select from, and i have to repeat the calls whenever i want to change the value or color of any of the labels. Please i need someone to help check if what i did here was/is the best way to o about it.

```
Private Sub listParameters_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lblParameter.MouseDown, lblParameter2.MouseDown, lblParameter3.Click, lblParameter4.Click, _
    lblParameter5.Click, lblParameter6.Click, lblParameter7.Click, lblParameter8.Click, lblParameter9.Click, lblParameter10.Click, lblParameter11.Click, lblParameter12.Click, lblParameter13.Click, lblParameter14.Click, lblParameter15.Click, _
           lblParameter16.Click, lblParameter17.Click, lblParameter18.Click, lblParameter19.Click, lblParameter20.Click, lblParameter21.Click, lblParameter22.Click, lblParameter23.Click, lblParameter24.Click, lblParameter25.Click, _
           lblParameter26.Click, lblParameter27.Click, lblParameter28.Click, lblParameter29.Click, lblParameter30.Click, lblParameter31.Click, lblParameter32.Click, lblParameter33.Click, lblParameter34.Click, lblParameter35.Click, _
    ListParameters.SelectedIndexChanged



    Select Case sender.Name
        Case "lblParameter"

            lblParameter.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter2"
            lblParameter2.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue2.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter3"
            lblParameter3.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue3.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter4"
            lblParameter4.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue4.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter5"
            lblParameter5.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue5.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter6"
            lblParameter6.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue6.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter7"
            lblParameter7.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue7.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter8"
            lblParameter8.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue8.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter9"
            lblParameter9.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue9.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter10"
            lblParameter10.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue10.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter11"
            lblParameter11.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue11.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter12"
            lblParameter12.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue12.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter13"
            lblParameter13.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue13.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter14"
            lblParameter14.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue14.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter15"
            lblParameter15.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue15.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter16"
            lblParameter16.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue16.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter17"
            lblParameter17.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue17.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter18"
            lblParameter18.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue18.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter19"
            lblParameter19.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue19.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter20"
            lblParameter20.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue20.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter21"
            lblParameter21.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue21.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter22"
            lblParameter22.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue22.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter23"
            lblParameter23.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue23.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter24"
            lblParameter24.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue24.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter25"
            lblParameter25.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue25.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter26"
            lblParameter26.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue26.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter27"
            lblParameter27.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue27.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter28"
            lblParameter28.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue28.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter29"
            lblParameter29.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue29.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter30"
            lblParameter30.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue30.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter31"
            lblParameter31.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue31.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter32"
            lblParameter32.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue32.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter33"
            lblParameter33.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue33.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter34"
            lblParameter34.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue34.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

        Case "lblParameter35"
            lblParameter35.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Medium Name").ToString
            lblValue35.Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem("Metric Conversion").ToString

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, and without using an IDE to try this, I would think you could just cast the sender back and set it's text from there. WITH the possibility of storing the lblValue in that parameter labels .Tag property so that you can cast it back and set its .text property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I'm talking about which should greatly reduce the code you have. You will need to go into each of the lblParameters and in the .Tag property put the name of the associated Value label (ie, lblValue for Parameter, lblValue2 for Parameter2, etc...) To test this, hilight your select case group and remark it out and put the following into that sub.

```
    Dim clickedLabel As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    clickedLabel.Text = ListParameters.Text
    DirectCast(Me.Controls(clickedLabel.Tag.ToString), Label).Text = ListParameters.SelectedValue.ToString
```

As you can see, were casting the sender to a label and setting its .Text property and then casting the control found with the name in the tag back to a label and setting its .Text property.

Comment: This kinda work to an extent, but it doesn't display the listboxes object again for me to make my selection before placing the selected items on the text properties of the associate clicked labels. Using the tag property work great. The casting work pretty  much and shorter than my initial long lines. but how do i resolved the listbox display and selection issues as earlier stated?

Comment: how are you filling that listbox? It's been a while, but I've not seen a parameter passed to SelectedItem as I thought this was all set from the DisplayMember and ValueMember's. Sorry, didn't really pay attention to what you were assigning when I set my example, just copied what you had. Are you meaning to use SelectedItem and SelectedValue's here?

Comment: The Listbox is populated from an access Datatable using the code below:Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source =C:\Current Weather.mdb")
        Dim DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Temp_Data]", connection)
        Dim ds As New DataTable("Definitions")

        connection.Open()

        DataAdapter.Fill(ds)

        ListParameters.DataSource = ds
        ListParameters.ValueMember = "Metric Conversion"
        ListParameters.DisplayMember = "Medium Name"

        connection.Close()

Comment: @Kelly OK, as I thought. I updated my answer to use the new information.

Comment: I want to display the selected items from the listbox items unto the LblParameter label property and the corresponding Value on the LblValue label text property. These are from dataset "ds"

Comment: Yes, that is what I have the code set to do. Is your listbox populating with the Medium Name like you expect?

Comment: This doesnt work, its throwing an error "Object variable or With block variable not set". "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".on this line :DirectCast(Me.Controls(clickedLabel.Tag.ToString), Label).Text = ListParameters.SelectedItem.ToString
        End If

Comment: That should be `SelectedValue` not `SelectedItem` but with that Error, I would suspect your tag property has the wrong label name in it.

Comment: Also note that that line is based on the labels being on the form. If they are in a panel or some other type of container control, the container will have to be specified.

Comment: Using SelectedValue DirectCast(Me.Controls(clickedLabel.Tag.ToString), Label).Text = ListParameters.SelectedValue.ToString, threw this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". And all the labels are placed on the form directly.

Comment: OK, so in the tag of the Parameter label, does the tag match an actual value label. Because that is looking for a label in the controls collection by the name specified in the tag and cast it back to a lable to get its .Text property. For example in your lblParameter what do you have in your tag property?

Comment: My bad please, i erronously deleted the dataset, But thats okay now, no more Errors, but listbox doesn't show yet. Please i forgot to mentioned that the listbox is placed on a groupbox, i named grbParameter. Thanks for the guide.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by listbox doesn't show yet. How have you been selecting listitems for the labels to use?

Comment: Charles, thanks a million. its finally resolved. i was calling the listbox directly rather than call its container visible property. Thanks for your time and patience man.

Comment: But one more thing sir, how do i save the form with all its controls and current selected parameters? such that when i reload the form its will display all the last selected parameters for the 35 lblParameter labels? Thanks for your positive responses thus far.

Comment: That might be better as a new question. I know there is a way to use settings to persist control settings but I personally prefer to use a database so I've never messed with settings. You could for each through the controls collection and save the .text properties to a database but you would have to have a way to determine what control holds what value for when you query the database for the saved information.